# Confusion with a function being "onto" and 1-1 correspondence.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If we are given an onto function $f : A \to B$, then this ensures that every element of $B$ corresponds to something in $A$.

But does this necessarily mean that the number of elements in set $B$ equates to that of the number of elements in set $A$?

My understanding is the answer to this is "no".

If my understanding is correct, then given a 1-1 correspondence between two sets $A$ and $B$ (i.e 1-1 and onto) does **THIS** then imply that the number of elements in sets $A$ and $B$ are equal?

Also, assume that $A$ and $B$ are finite sets. I do not want to necessarily talk about cardinality of infinite domains.

Comment: Yes, it means that $f$ is a bijection, and this is one of the definitions of "equal in size" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it means that $f$ is a bijection ("1-1" means injective, "onto" means surjective), and this is one of the definitions of "equal in size".

In my opinion, these notions are confusing beyond usability, but the consensus is that:

- "1-1" or "1-1 mapping" means injective, i.e., no element of $B$ has more than one pre-image;
- "1-1 correspondance" means injective both ways, i.e., bijective.

I prefer to use:

- "onto" for surjective;
- "injective" for injective;
- "bijective" for bijective.

However, in many real cases, there are more proper names as "factors", "homo/endo/auto/iso-morphisms", "conjugations" etc., so you then don't meet the basic notions so often.

Comment: Okay, thank you mate.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question,
the answer is "no".
For example,
the function
$[x]$
(integer part)
maps the reals onto the integers.

For the second,
the existence of a 1-1 correspondence
is the usual *definition*
of having the same number of elements
for infinite sets.

Answer (score 1):

If f:A→B is a surjective (onto) function then |A|≥|B| and f is a bijection iff the cardinality of A and B are equal (even if they are infinite sets)

Comment: I think that it would be better to write $|A| \ge |B|$.

Comment: yes true that, i edit it now